# Will Landscape tool help pull in user logs from the client

Tags: logs

I would like to know if Landscape can monitor the user login logs and report.
Whenever a user is switching as root, he becomes privileged user so I need to keep a track of the user. Hence will Landscape track the logs of the privileged users.

Comment: The file /var/log/auth.log keeps track on logins. `grep sudo /var/log/auth.log` in terminal will show you all commands issued by users using `sudo`, for example.